# Why is this array null when it has already been initialized?

Tags: java, arrays

I am confused as to why this array (cumulativeWeights) is said to be null. Here is my (simplified) code:

```
public class WeightedDieTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WeightedDie d = new WeightedDie();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Die
{
    public Die()
    {
        this.roll();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class WeightedDie extends Die {
    double[] cumulativeWeights = {.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, 1};

    public WeightedDie() {
    }
    public int roll() {

        for (int i = 0; i < cumulativeWeights.length; i++) { //this is where the nullpointerException is occuring
            if (randNum < cumulativeWeights[i]) {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        return 6;
    }
}
```

So yeah, cumulativeWeights has been initialized and should not be null. Does anyone know why it I am getting that nullpointerexception?

Comment: Because you're calling `roll()` inside the `Die` constructor before `cumulativeWeights` has been assigned.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Is `Die` an abstract class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the constructor of the super class, the fields of a class are not initialized. You should call roll not from this point. Instances are initialized (and constructors are called) from the farthest super class down to the instance's class.

Answer (score 3):

Java executes in this order

```
Parent static block
Child static block
Parent initialization  block
Parent Constructor
Child initialization block
Child Constructor
```

Hence , when you call roll from Die , array is not initialized yet.

Answer (score 2):

Took a lot of time for me to figure it out myself,

Firstly, there are some basic mistakes that you have done in your code

1. You shouldn't call overridable methods from a constructor. Here you are calling the `roll()` function, which is being overriden in the child class.

   ```
   public Die()
   {
       this.roll(); // shouldn't be done.
   }
   ```

2.You don't get a compile time error because you have declared the variable `cumulativeWeights` in your child class. Since the object of `WeightedDie` is not completed yet, the values to those variables are not yet initialized.

3.Since values are not initialized to `cumulativeWeights`, you are getting a null pointer exception. (But it is already declared so the compiler let's you compile without errors)

4.See the output of the below formatted code. And next time be careful while calling an overridable method from your constructor

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Die
{
    public double[] cumulativeWeights = {.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, 1};
    public Die()
    {
        System.out.println("constructing die");
        this.roll();
    }
    public int roll(){
        return 1;
    }
}
class WeightedDie extends Die {
     int randNum = 33; // value 0 is used because randNum isn't even initialized
    // even in your code!! cumulativeWeights is just declared, so no compile time error, you are using it even before the constructor of the child class is called!!!!
    public WeightedDie() {
        System.out.println("constructing weighteddie");
    }
    @Override
    public int roll() {
        System.out.println("using weighteddie and randNum = "+randNum);
        for (int i = 0; i < cumulativeWeights.length; i++) { //this is where the nullpointerException is occuring
            if (randNum < cumulativeWeights[i]) {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        return 6;
    }
}
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WeightedDie d = new WeightedDie();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
constructing die
using weighteddie and randNum = 0
constructing weighteddie
```

I hope you got my point. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If the cumulativeWeights is not object specific data then make it static.